# How to get argument from argv with spaces?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I want to write program that can get string as argument. But string like `"Hell o   w o r l d"` will loose all the spaces if i am trying to get it from `argv`. Is there a way to get number of spaces between each two of arguments, or better just get `argv` as string?

Comment: How are you *starting* your program?  If there are spaces in *any one command-line argument*, they will be preserved when passed to the program.  But spaces are usually delimiters used to *separate* arguments when parsed by a command shell before they're passed to a program.

Comment: That's why some programs use markers like double `--option_xyz=` so they can reconstruct strings with spaces. And others allow you to pass strings with spaces in quotes. Just pick a mechanism and document it

Answer (score 2):

One way to preserve the spaces in the original string is to put the string in quotes when passing it as an argument. For example, if you want to pass the string "Hello world" as an argument, you would run the program like this:

```
./file "Hello World"
```

Then, in your program, you can access the original string, including the spaces, by using argv[1].